# How to make a layout transparent on an image view

Tags: android, android-layout

How do I display a transparent layout on an image view in Android?

I have a linear layout on an image view, both in a layout. I want the linear layout to be transparent on the image view. Can we do it?

Comment: Try android:background="#00000000"

Comment: I gave a layout(vertical) with a text view in it..and an image view 
. I want the text view to be displayed transparent on image view.. Can u give me an example which supports this question??

Comment: Accept the answer, if its done, Kameny give right answer. If you accept it is usefull for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this attribute :

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: i have changed it to android:background=#80000000" and it worked..partially transparent.

Comment: Yes, it works fine. If you put 80 before your color it will be transparent. [For more information.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color)

Answer (score 0):

```
// "image transparent programmatically android"    


float alpha_first = 0.2f;
    float alpha_second = 1.0f;
        AlphaAnimation alphadp = new AlphaAnimation(alpha_second, alpha_first);
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.disable_deactivate_pic:
            ImageButton disable_button =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.disable_deactivate_pic);
                    if (!flag) {
                        disable_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.enable_active);

                        linearLayout_for_picture = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout_imageView_pic);

                    alphadp.setFillAfter(true);
                    linearLayout_for_picture.startAnimation(alphadp);
                    flag=true;
                    }
            else {
                        disable_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.disable_active);
                        alphadp.setFillAfter(false);
                        linearLayout_for_picture.startAnimation(alphadp);
                        flag=false;
                    }

                break;








      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0V2V.png
```